# How does Azure AD validates against the windows credentials[ login.microsoftonline.com/ <tenant_id>/oauth2/authorize ]

Tags: windows, azure, validation, azure-active-directory, credentials

We have internal tools and are access through SSO Azure AD. I am curious to know how this Azure AD validate against windows credentials.
 For example say, 
1) we have internal DEV env. https::/auth/v1/session/profile so when I call this instance it redirects to https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&scope=directory.read.all&response_mode=query&redirect_uri=&client_id=>&resource=&state=&nonce=&sso_nonce=&mscrid= .
2) After entering the email id it redirects to https::/auth/v1/token with the JWT token as response. 
 So curious to know in #1 how does the login.microsoftonline.com validates that I am the authorized user. Does it takes windows credentials internally or take some session from my window system? Please clarify.

Comment: Do you have a hybrid environment with on-premise Active Directory? Or only cloud Azure AD?

Comment: Yes, we have a hybrid environment with an on-premise Active Directory.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how your hybrid environment is setup, you can see the options here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/choose-ad-authn.

It might be redirecting you to ADFS to login, which figures out that you are already logged in to the company network and does some kind of Kerberos magic to sign you in.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/whatis-fed

Or you might have e.g. Password Hash Sync + Seamless Single Sign-On enabled, in which case Azure AD either does Kerberos authentication against your on-premise AD, or your Azure AD-joined machine's primary refresh token is used behind the scenes.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sso